# How to exclude a certain CPT from a snippet for Dashboard box?

Tags: custom-post-types, dashboard

I have this snippet for the "At a glance" Dashboard box to show not only posts, pages, but also custom post types.
So far, so good, but now I want to exclude a special custom post type called:

avia_framework_post

What must I add to this snippet to exclude it from showing in this dashboard box?

```
<?php
function kb_add_cpts_to_dashboard() {
 $args = array(
 'public' => true,
 '_builtin' => false
 );

$output = 'object';
 $operator = 'and';

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
 
 foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
 $num_posts = wp_count_posts( $post_type->name );
 $num = number_format_i18n( $num_posts->publish );
 $text = _n( $post_type->labels->singular_name, $post_type->labels->name, intval( $num_posts->publish ) );
 if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
 $output = '<a href="edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type->name . '">' . $num . ' ' . $text . '</a>';
 echo '<li class="post-count ' . $post_type->name . '-count">' . $output . '</li>';
 }
 }
}

add_action( 'dashboard_glance_items', 'kb_add_cpts_to_dashboard' );
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Unset the post type from the returned array. `unset( $post_types['avia_framework_post'] );` after the `get_post_types` call but before the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe just one small edit to your code would get what you want. See if this works, just change the one `if()` statement to the following:

`if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && $post_type !== 'avia_framework_post' )`

Comment: thank you, works fine!